# Can't access Public API with C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a request against the public API from Etoro (Trading App) via C#.
If I call the URI in an Browser all works fine. For example:
`https://www.etoro.com/sapi/trade-data-real/live/public/portfolios?format=json&cid=3180395&client_request_id=8ae032db-7642-4b48-9628-b635a29aefba`

But if I ran my program, sometimes it works, but most of the time I got an "Error 512".

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Der Antwortstatuscode gibt keinen Erfolg an: 512 (Unknown Code)."

Are there errors in my code, or is it a problem with the user-agent, or something else? Any ideas?

```
{
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cUrl
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string responseBody { get; set; }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid uuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.etoro.com/sapi/trade-data-real/live/public/portfolios?format=json&cid=3180395" + "&client_request_id=" + uuid);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(client.BaseAddress);
            
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not disposing of your HttpClient, and you are mistaking BaseAddress for full Uri.

Comment: Please could you tell me how the command than should be used? I ried some varinats but always the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I tryed it using browser or Postman sometimes I got a result , sometime an error

```
"error":{"failureReason":"Something went wrong, please try again"}
```

So I think it is the API's problem, not client's.

Comment: Yes, that was an solution I was thinking about too. But when i refresh my browser, this error is shown very rare. When I try my application  it is working for one or two times and then it doesn't work anymore... Very strange behavior. Eventuelly it is as you mentioned and the Problem is on Serverside, but this API is used very heavy by the hole tradingplatform... For now I think they are blocking the app, because of some false behavior. Thank you for helping!